# Ошибка при написании собственной монады Writer в новой версии ghci

Tags: haskell

У меня есть такой код:

```
newtype MyWriter w a = MyWriter { runWriter :: (a, w) }

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (MyWriter w) where
    return x = MyWriter (x, mempty)
    m >>= k =
        let (x, u) = runWriter m
            (y, v) = runWriter $ k x
        in MyWriter (y, u `mappend` v)
```

Если его запустить в новой версии `ghci`, то можно увидеть такое сообщение об ошибке:

```
Could not deduce (Applicative (MyWriter w))
```

Окей. Добавляю импорт import `Control.Monad (ap, liftM)` и следующий код перед `instance (Monoid w) => Monad (MyWriter w)`:

```
instance Functor (Monoid w) => Monad (MyWriter w) where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative (Monoid w) => Monad (MyWriter w) where
  pure = return
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
‘fmap’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Monad’
‘pure’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Monad’
```

Не понимаю как это поправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы чуток ошиблись в объявлении новых двух инстансов. Нужно объявить инстансы `Functor (MyWriter w)` и `Applicative (MyWriter w)`:

```
instance Functor (MyWriter w) where
  fmap = ...

instance Applicative (MyWriter w) where
  (<|>) = ...
  pure = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой, когда занимался по незабвенному "Изучай Хаскелл...". Добавлю к предыдущему оратору еще один рецепт (модифицированный код из книжки). В отличии от ↑, используется не кастомный `MyWriter`, а родной библиотечный `Control.Monad.Writer`, для этого надо исползовать функцию `writer` (с маленькой буквы):

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int
logNumber x = writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])
...
```

---

PS Кстати, в новой версии книжки (в отличии от версии на сайте), именно такой фрагмент кода и содержится. И даже ниже автор обращает на это внимание:

> Notice how we used the writer function to construct a Writer value,
>   instead of directly using the Writer value constructor.